# Laravel Backpack export tables in excel and pdf through code

Tags: laravel-backpack

I am using laravel backpack to brows database entries

To add excel and pdf export functionality, i am using the `$this->crud->enableExportButtons();` function inside  MyCrudController.

Generating the export by user interface work great, but I would like to be able to generate an export through code, so i can attach it to a daily cronjob.

Does anyone know if its possible to hook into the export function, to save exports to memory or disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Backpack won't help you with server-side exports, since it uses DataTables to export the data, which uses JavaScript. Using Backpack's export server-side would be very very difficult.

But you should be able to export to excel from a cron job using [this package](https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/).